# linked list while statement (addTwoNumbers from LeetCode)

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

Below is the code that I submitted and subsequently got accepted.

```
class Solution(object):
def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2):
    """
    :type l1: ListNode
    :type l2: ListNode
    :rtype: ListNode
    """
    result = ListNode(0)
    result_tail = result
    carry = 0

    while l1 or l2 or carry:        

        val1  = (l1.val if l1.val else 0)
        val2  = (l2.val if l2.val else 0)

        out = (val1+val2 + carry)%10
        carry = (val1+val2 + carry)//10

        result_tail.next = ListNode(out)
        result_tail = result_tail.next                      

        l1 = (l1.next if l1.next else None)
        l2 = (l2.next if l2.next else None)

    return result.next
```

Initially, I had `while l1.val or l2.val or carry:` but it was rejected with an error message saying the following :

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has njo attribute 'val'

But, the linked node lists l1 and l2 clearly have attributes val and next.

I am not sure why `while l1.val or l2.val or carry:` did not work.

Below is the code I originally submitted but got rejected.

```
class Solution(object):
def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2):
    """
    :type l1: ListNode
    :type l2: ListNode
    :rtype: ListNode
    """
    result = ListNode(0)
    result_tail = result
    carry = 0

    print(l1.val)
    print(l2.val)
    while l1.val or l2.val or carry:        

        val1  = (l1.val if l1.val else 0)
        val2  = (l2.val if l2.val else 0)

        out = (val1+val2 + carry)%10
        carry = (val1+val2 + carry)//10

        result_tail.next = ListNode(out)
        result_tail = result_tail.next                      

        l1 = (l1.next if l1.next else None)
        l2 = (l2.next if l2.next else None)

    return result.next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `l1` or `l2` are a `NoneType`, or essentially `None`, which means they actually *aren't* the type you expect. How does `None` get in here? Well, one of two ways:

The first, is that somebody could pass in `None` as on of the inputs, `l1` or `l2`.

The second, which is almost guaranteed to be your problem, is that it comes from the following statements:

```
        l1 = (l1.next if l1.next else None)
        l2 = (l2.next if l2.next else None)
```

In other words, if there isn't a next value, we're going to make sure we set it to None. Then, because we loop on the condition that `l1 or l2 or carry`, only one of these has to be "truthy". In other words, it's possible `l1` was None, and `l2` was a valid list on the next iteration, or vice-versa... or carry was truthy. Or both.

A truth table for your condition `l1 or l2 or carry` to visualize better:

```
l1 | l2 | carry | result
------------------------
T---T----T------|   T
T---F----T------|   T
T---T----F------|   T
T---F----F------|   T
F---T----T------|   T
F---F----T------|   T
F---T----F------|   T
F---F----F------|   F
```

Since `None` is a "falsy" type, `None` will evaluate to `False`, but it will take all three of those conditions to be `False` to not continue the loop.

As for the prints at the beginning, they are *before* the while loop, so every time you iterate that loop, `l1` and `l2` get a different value. You've made sure that what was *passed in* wasn't `None`. But it didn't stop `l1` and `l2` from becoming `None` later.

Comment: I see the potential issues with my solution.  But, for the specific test case,I did try 'print(l1.val)  print(l2.val)' to make sure that the test case wasn't passing in 'None'

Comment: @stratofortress Where did you have your print statement? Are you sure you weren't just printing `val1` and `val2`? You would have seen a `None` value if you were printing that before it crashed if you printed `l1` and `l2` before accessing them. Plain and simple.

Comment: Thank you for your comment again.  I just added the original submission below my accepted code.  I printed l1.val and l2.val to make sure that they weren't 'None'

Comment: @stratofortress I appended some more information to my answer. You printed `None` before your `while` loop. That prints once, the `while` loop can execute indefinitely, and modify `l1` and `l2` every time it runs.

Answer (score 0):

There might have been a test case where the value passed in for l1 and/or l2 was None. If this happened, then an AttributeError would be raised because None does not have any such attribute - it is simply None (null in other languages).

Note that you fixed this problem for checking None by simply removing .val from each l1 and l2 in the while statement. This is why the second submission was accepted successfully.

Comment: do you think it should have worked?   I looked at the test case and I think it never passed None for either l1 or l2.

Comment: Even if the test cases did not pass None for either l1 or l2, it is best to still check for all cases. There may have also been a case where inside of the loop, after update, either l1 or l2 became None, again justifying the need for handling the case when l1 and/or l2 are None. Note: you achieved this when you changed the code to just l1 or l2 instead of l1.val or l2.val